# Generate po or xml file for language translation

Tags: expressionengine, language-translation

I just need a clearance from expert. I need to translate whole site in other language. My site is consist of the 100 of articles. I need to get that whole article translated. Should I create .po or xml file for each article

If above is only way then let me know efficient way to create .po and xml files as these are not small messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've tagged your post with 'expressionengine', so I'm assuming that your site is built on EE.  In which case, neither .po files nor XML files are the way to go. Since EE offers completely customizable fields and channels, you can have you secondary language content managed just like your primary language content.

There are many different approaches to this in EE, each with their own pros and cons. This article linked below gives a great overview of the many approaches, and offers many links to additional reading. It's more than one answer on SO can properly cover.

*[Multi-language Solutions for ExpressionEngine](http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine/) on EE Insider*

Comment: yes, we already implemented multi language stuff but now to we need to get all stuff translated and the translators required the string files in po or xml. so how that can be provided ?

Comment: Do read the article that Derek has directed you to, as it explains many aspects of implementing multi-language solutions, from database encoding to working with translators. Look at the paragraphs under "Working with professional translators" for answers relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To export as XML:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it
or
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export

Alternatively you can simply build a template that outputs the XML using standard {exp:channel:entries} tag pair, making the template type XML and adding the correct header and code for XML.

To re-import:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab

All of the above will involve knowing what fields you want to export out along with their table and row references so it can easily be re-imported.

Strongly suggest you thoroughly test the export and import facility you opt for to ensure it works before beginning any translation process.

Example XML Template (this is to build sitemap.xml but gives you a start on building your own XML structure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" entry_id="not 117|104" limit="500" disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" rdf="off" dynamic="no" status="Open" sort="asc"}
    <url>
        <loc>{page_url}</loc>
        <lastmod>{gmt_edit_date format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</urlset>
```